# Mapping hibernate entity Many to one

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I’m a little lost in my hibernate mapping.

I have these entity :

```
CommandLine : 

idCommand
idCommandeLine
idItem
idStore
dateCommand


Item : 

idItem
libItem
price


Store : 

idStore
idWarehouse
libStore


Warehouse : 

idWarehouse
libWarehouse


Stock : 

idItem
idWarehouse
qtyStock
```

I want to add a qtyStock attribute in CommandLine.

The goal is, when I loop thought commandLines object, I can get the qtyStock of the item.
Based on the idStore, we can get the idWarehouse, and get the qty.

But how translate this in my hibernate XML Mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use HBM XML mappings. The annotation mapping model is the preferred choice and you will find plenty of tutorials and help here for that model. If you really must use HBM XML mappings, we need more details. What did you try so far and did not work? How do your current mappings look like?